# mod_rewrite with .htaccess to make dynamic page search engine friendly

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make search engine friendly pages with *.htaccess*.

The page look like `/en/hotel.php?id=nice-hotel-7-patterson-street` and I would like the page to look like this `/en/nice-hotel-7-patterson-street` or `/en/hotel-nice-hotel-7-patterson-street`.

I am using this in my *.htaccess* file at the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$          hotel.php?id=$2 [L]
```

but it does not seem to work in the `/en/` folder and does not seem to work if letters are in the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is incorrect. Since / is missing from the first part of the expression, it will not match anything which is in a sub-directory. Since the last expression requires there to be numbers at the end, it would work with URL that end in letters as per your examples.

You must generalize your expression, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ hotel.php?id=$1
```

Now if you have multiple directories, you have to match that and pass it on somewhere different. If you have one hotel.php file in each directory use the first line below, if you have only one in all, use the second line where the directory is passed as another parameter, so that you can output different contents.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1/hotel.php?id=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ hotel.php?id=$2&lang=$1
```

Comment: Thank you Itai, the code you provided 

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1/hotel.php?id=$2 

seems to work, I was wondering if it would be possible to display the page with a .htm extension

such as

/en/nice-hotel-7-patterson-street.htm or /en/hotel-nice-hotel-7-patterson-street.htm

Comment: @user29044 - Just at `\.htm` before the `$` in the rule. Also please remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem.